# How to do a try / retry / except?

Tags: python, exception, try-except

Is there a way to avoid nested `try / except` when there are **3 cases** (a bit like `if` `elif` `else`)?

```
try:
    name = open("test.txt", "r").read()            # test in current folder
except FileNotFoundError:
    try:
        name = open("c:/test.txt", "r").read()     # test in drive root
    except FileNotFoundError:
        name = "empty"                             # not found
```

Note: this is just an example of a general case `try/retry/except`, so here I'm not interested for a solution with `if os.path.exists(...)`, which I already know, or other solutions which would be specific to this file  open example.

Comment: If youre asking if theres some special language construct/syntax to do this, there is not. `try` blocks can have mutliple `except` blocks, an `else` block that runs if theres no error and a `finally` block that always runs. So, for the `elif` case, you'd have to nest another `try` block.

Comment: Couldn't you just loop through the specific values?

Answer (score 2):

How about having a list of files to check and trying them in a loop:

```
files = ['test.txt', 'c:/test.txt']
for f in files:
    try:
       name = open(f).read()
    except FileNotFound:
       pass
    else:
       break
else:
    name = 'empty'
```

Comment: Thanks @bereal but as mentioned in the question, I'm really looking for a *general* way to do try / retry / except (if it exists), not other ways that would only apply to this specific example with files.

Comment: I think this method works for anything if you know what the exception is, and what the list to be iterated on in advance are, no? Just replace `files = [...` with `list_to_iterate = [...` and `except FileNotFound` with `except knownException`, obviously and the try with the real try.

Answer (score 0):

Nested functions with early return are sometimes helpful.

```py
def process_test():
    def try_try_again():
        try:
            return open("test.txt", "r").read()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
        try:
            return open("c:/test.txt", "r").read()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            return "empty"
    name = try_try_again()
```

[`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) can make it a bit less verbose

```
import contextlib

def process_test():
    def try_try_again():
        with contextlib.suppress(FileNotFoundError):
            return open("test.txt", "r").read()
        with contextlib.suppress(FileNotFoundError):
            return open("c:/test.txt", "r").read()
        return "empty"
    name = try_try_again()
```